# Using (of) or (in) with the word "member"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

Actually I find it hard in a lot of occasions to know when to use "in" and when to use "of". One of those cases comes with the word "member" as follows  :

1- He is member in the group of math.

2- He is member of the group of math.

And, is it true that if I want to talk about new member I should use "to"? For instance: He is the new member to the group of math.

Comment: You're usually a member ***of*** a group, not ***in*** the group. And it's usually ***math group*** rather than ***group of math***. But getting those "wrong" is a trivial issue compared to the out-and-out error of failing to include an article before "member" - ***He is a member of the math group***.

Comment: The use of "to" in your last question is not correct. You can be new to something, like "I am new to driving" or "She is new to the group". But the word "to" would be incorrect in the example you gave due to the possessive nature of the intended meaning. You become a new member `of` a group, therefore "he is the new member of the group".

Comment: He is a member of the math group. He is in the math group. He is a new member of the math group. He is new to the math group. All of these are correct.